# how to exec a shell script from java which does tomcat restart and still continue to run

Tags: java, linux, unix, tomcat

I have  java application which runs on tomcat. I have shell script which does tomcat restart and then executes other unix commands. so from my application(java code) when i run this shell scrit, once the tomcat is restarted it exits from the shell script and doesn't run the unix commands after the tomcat restart.

i know that when we run the shell script from java, it is run by tomcat as the parent and when tomcat is restarted it will kill the parent process so the command after tomcat restart are not executed.

is there a way to run the shell script even after tomcat is restarted... i tried using different options like nohup, /bin/sh -c and none of them  work... and once the tomcat is restarted the script dies.

Comment: You'd probably have to run it from something other that the tomcat which you are restarting. Think about it, if you order your computer to shut-down and then open notepad, do you think the notepad would open?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to keep the thread alive since the JVM is restarted. However, you could have a servlet with `load-on-startup` set to `1` (or some other non-zero value). The `init()` function will then be executed when Tomcat starts. You could have the rest of the commands in there. Of course, this would run no matter how Tomcat was restarted.

More on load-on-startup: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html#load-on-startup